# Developing AngularJS 1.6 application without NodeJS.

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, java

What are the points to keep in mind for application using AngularJS v1.6 without Node.

This application will connect with Java API and using eclipse for local development.

What are the possible drawbacks one can face in such scenario including deployment scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, agreed. Previously I have worked on Angular apps  with node managing all its dependencies. So just wanted to make sure that I don’t miss out any important pointer to keep in mind when developing **without** NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

You **`can`** have Angularjs application without node as independent.

**`node.js`** is used to write Javascript on the **`server side`**. You can install npm (node packaged modules) to use some awesome tools that will make your life as an angular developer much easier.

They use to go together as the **`MEAN`** Stack. You can have your Java API separately and a separate standalone SPA application which consumes those services.

There are certain things that you may need to consider such as,

- CORS
- Package Management
- Bundling